# Two Part PHP form skip detection

Tags: php, forms, workflow

I have a two part php form.

> Part 1 - Agreement Page.  .. you have to accept this to proceed forward to part 2
>   yes > proceed no > redirect to another page.
>
> Part 2 - form itself. 
>   fill form > proceed to thank you.

How do prevent people from going to part 2 directly? ex.  `part1-p1.php`, `part2-p2.php`.  If I load `part2-p2.php` then it detects that you didn't come from `part1-p1.php` and redirects you to `part1-p1.php`.

any snippets or web references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Session` for this condition, after the user agrees the agreement, set `$_SESSION['agree'] = true`, when loading part 2, check `$_SESSION[agree]` first

Answer (score 0):

I personally like @LotusH's answer. However I figured I would offer another suggestion in case you are not using sessions (or don't want to for whatever reason).

You could have part1 page post to part 2 page.  If the expected POST values for acceptance are not present (or if page2 is not posting back onto itself), you could redirect to the non-acceptance page.